# presentMediaPlayerController(with:options:completion:)' has been explicitly marked unavailable here

Tags: objective-c, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

I am trying to play sound using the apple watch speakers

I am getting these error messages

```
'presentMediaPlayerController(with:options:completion:)' is unavailable
```

also:

```
WatchKit.WKInterfaceController:28:15: note: 'presentMediaPlayerController(with:options:completion:)' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
```

and here is the code that generates the error:

```
    presentMediaPlayerController(with: soundURL, options: ["WKMediaPlayerControllerOptionsAutoplayKey":true]) { (a, b, c) in

    }
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What version watch os are you running this code on? Is it possible it has to do with WatchKit 1 vs 2

Comment: @Yan How can I verify this? thanx in advance

Comment: I haven't use apple watch but I am in settings -> general -> about